# In FreeMarket, what does the target use in a Breaking or Ghosting Aggregate Challenge?

Tags: freemarket

In FreeMarket, what does the target use in a Breaking or Ghosting Aggregate Challenge?

Assuming, of course, that the target is the superuser, playing the Aggregate. For a Switching challenge, the manual explains things clearly enough, providing geneline and experience ratings to use; but for Breaking and Ghosting, the "Target Uses:" heading only says "[Breaking|Ghosting] or appropriately tagged geneline." The Aggregate has no Experience ratings or Geneline... so what do you use?

Answer (score 4):

Page 120 lists the profile for a sweep.